# Extending Ember JSONAPIAdapter findAll for fetching json from custom url

Tags: javascript, django, rest, api, ember.js

I'm relatively new to Ember.js and I'm trying to studing how ember works and I've this problem:
from an Ember.js route I will call my django api like this: `this.store.findAll('MYMODEL', 'ANOTHER_MODEL_ID')`

This findAll will produce an api call like /mymodel/*another_model_id*/ where *another_model_id* is a dynamic id (uuid like string).

I've tried to override the findAll method with a custom adapter (mymodel adapter) that extends the ApplicationAdapter (JSONAPIAdapter with a custom buildUrl for adding trailing slash). But my attempt failed, because in findAll overridden method I can't reach the *ANOTHER_MODEL_ID* parameter. I've also tried to override urlForFindAll and buildUrl methods with the same results.

What is the best method for doing this kind of things and how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved using urlForQuery function and declaring my adapter as JSONAPIAdapter extending it with DataAdapterMixin.

Answer (score 0):

findAll has no id argument. Do you mean find('modelname', 'id')?

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Adapter.extend({
  findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken) {
    var query = { since: sinceToken };
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Ember.$.getJSON(`/${type.modelName}`, query).then(function(data) {
        resolve(data);
      }, function(jqXHR) {
        reject(jqXHR);
      });
    });
  }
});
```